# Custom structure in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter

How can I build a custom structure like this in flutter?
[image: Ticket Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Path](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0) and [Clipper](https://medium.com/flutter-community/clipping-in-flutter-e9eaa6b1721a). You have to follow carefully these steps to archieve it